# Shopify - 401 error during webrequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, shopify

I am facing some serious issue with Shopify during web request to get order list from my application while I am getting fine with direct hit on browser.

here is the code :

```
    private const string APIKey = "[DELETED]";
        private const string APIPassword = "[DELETED]";
        private const string APISecrateKey = "[DELETED]";
        private const string StoreName = "epronto-2";
        private const string OrderURL = "https://" + APIKey + ":" + APIPassword + "@" + StoreName + ".myshopify.com/admin/orders.json";
        public string gethttpResponse(){
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            req.Headers.Add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", APISecrateKey);
            string text = string.Empty;
            try{
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch{}
            return text;
        }
```

can you please suggest what i am missing here.

**What I have tried:**

actually, I am getting data from the private app,I read many articles and found there is no required for permanent access_token via OAuth API,

so I added
req.Headers.Add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", APISecrateKey);
this line , but I could not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

try adding `req.credentials(apikey,apipassword);`

I was having the same issue but had tried a mix of approaches and inadvertently had both in my code that was working. I took that line out  thinking it was superfluous and could not figure out why my code broke until I saw your post and tried adding it back.

my code is now"

```
 WebRequest OrderRequest = WebRequest.Create("<url like you build>");
   OrderRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential"APIKEY", "APIpassword");
   response = (HttpWebResponse)OrderRequest.GetResponse();
```

after a bit of testing, I altered your code and this is working:

```
 public static string gethttpResponse(Uri url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            //req.Headers.Add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", APISecrateKey);
            req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(APIKey, APIPassword);
            string text = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
                Utility.LogMessage(a.ToString());
            }
            return text;
        }
```